# Subscribe to Event using a Delegate

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling

I'm trying to subscribe to the `MouseUp` event for all controls on my form except for Buttons. I used a loop to subscribe all of the controls which works fine. But I want to be able to use this function on more than one form so instead of always subscribing the same function to the event, I want to pass a function as a parameter. So I created a delegate but I get this error:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'namespace.frmSettings.MouseUpDelegate' to 'System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler'`

Can you please tell me if what I'm trying to do is possible and if so, what am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
public frmSettings()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Subscribe to MouseUp events for key binds
    SubscribeMouseClicks(this, new MouseUpDelegate(frmSettings_MouseUp));
}

private delegate void MouseUpDelegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e);
private void SubscribeMouseClicks(Control parentControl, MouseUpDelegate mouseUpDelegate)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in parentControl.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl.GetType() != typeof(Button))
        {
            ctrl.MouseUp += mouseUpDelegate; //This line causes the error. If I change mouseUpDelegate to frmSettings_MouseUp it works
            if (ctrl.HasChildren)
            {
                SubscribeMouseClicks(ctrl, mouseUpDelegate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried searching for an answer but can't find what I'm looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just use `MouseEventHandler` where you now use `MouseUpDelegate`. You don't need your own delegate type if you can do with the one that is provided.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not working either. Now it's saying it cannot convert `frmSettings.MouseEventHandler` to `System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare a brand new delegate to do this. `MouseUp` event is defined using a delegate type, `MouseEventHandler`. This means that you just need to store an instance of `MouseEventHandler`.

So remove this declaration:

```
private delegate void MouseUpDelegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e);
```

And write the method like so:

```
private void SubscribeMouseClicks(Control parentControl, MouseEventHandler eventHandler)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in parentControl.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl.GetType() != typeof(Button))
        {
            ctrl.MouseUp += eventHandler;
            if (ctrl.HasChildren)
            {
                SubscribeMouseClicks(ctrl, eventHandler);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
SubscribeMouseClicks(this, frmSettings_MouseUp);
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually worked that out as you posted the answer (rene's comment pointed me in that direction). I didn't realise you could pass a function name as parameter.

Comment: @Daniel You can always pass a method as a parameter if the parameter's type is a delegate and the two signatures match.